# Двоеточие в URL вызывает 403 - как бороться?

Tags: .htaccess, url

Делаю движок, в котором необходимо использовать двоеточие в URL-е, наподобии как в [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:PHP).

Появилась проблема: при заходе на такой адрес выскакивает `403` ошибка, игнорируя все предписания для `mod_rewrite` в `.htaccess`.
Искал в гугле. Многие люди жаловались на это, но решения я так и не нашел. Еще было оговорено, что ошибка появляется только в windows-системах.
Решается ли оно как-то?

```
upd: Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3 Windows XP SP3 x86
```

Comment: Вы спрашиваете как пользователь? Попросите программистов сайта починить.

Вы спрашиваете как программист? Разберитесь, что происходит с HTTP-запросом, который приходит на ваш сайт. Вы нам даже не сказали, какой сервер вы используете. (Может, вообще самописный.)

Comment: Как программер.
Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) PHP/5.3.3 Windows XP SP3 x86

Comment: А что будет, если в URL серверу вместо двоеточия будет отправлено `%3A` ? То же самое ?

Answer (score 2):

решений как минимум два:

1. перекомпилировать *apache* так, чтобы он не блокировал *url-ы*, содержащие <kbd>:</kbd> (двоеточие, *colon*).
2. запускать *apache* в операционной системе, отличной от *ms/windows*.

использование двоеточия в путях к файлам в операционной системе *ms/windows* чревато проблемами. подробнее — в [сообщении об «ошибке» в программе *apache*](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441).

другие найденные упоминания на сайте so:

- [access forbidden on url containing colon symbol, “:”, on apache windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33516625/4827341)
- [Mod Rewrite and passing a URL as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10440048/4827341)
- [Is it possible to handle such URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2923247/4827341)

Answer (score -1):

Если вы только делаете движок, то зачем плодить проблемы? Есть стандарт. Двоеточие символ зарезервированный для указания протокола и порта. Не все вебсервера обрабатывают этот символ в адресе нормально. 
Apache под Windows раньше этим страдал, не знаю как счас.

И даже если вы решите проблему сейчас, нет гарантии, что она не проявится позже. Не стоит идти по граблям.

Comment: @fStrange: вы хотите сказать, что URI в википедии нарушают RFC? Если нет, не сбивайте автора вопроса с толку.

Answer (score -1):

[urlencode()](http://www.php.su/functions/?urlencode)